# Generate different clickable events on Divs in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a very simple `Shiny` app as below -

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(id = "01", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", HTML("01")),
  div(id = "02", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: blue", HTML("02")),
  div(id = "03", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: red", HTML("03")),

  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
}
```

Within this framework, I want to achieve a clickable event over the three `divs` wherein click on first `div` would generate a `cdf plot of Normal distribution`, 2nd `div` would generate `t distribution` and 3rd one would generate a `GED distribution`.

I can use a `drop-down box` etc. to achieve the same, alternatively, I may also use 3 different `plotOutput()` for each div. However in my present case I have too many such `divs` which therefore would not be feasible to have so many individual `plotOutput()`. So I desire to have such functionality through individual `divs` with one output.

Is there any way to achieve the same in `Shiny`? Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would use ```shinyjs``` with the ```onclick``` function but I am having trouble displaying a plot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @bretauv `shinyjs` has `onclick` function, so you an do the following, note that you have to provide the plots with distributions I am simply doing the changes with the normal

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
    column(3,
           div(id = "01", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", HTML("01")),
           div(id = "02", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: blue", HTML("02")),
           div(id = "03", style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: red", HTML("03")),
    ),
    column(9,
           plotOutput("plot")
    )
)

v <- reactiveValues()

normal <- function(v){
    v$x <- seq(-10, 10, by = .1)
    v$y <- rnorm(v$x)
    v$title <- "Normal distribution"
}

tdistr <- function(v){
    v$x <- seq(-10, 10, by = .1)
    v$y <- rnorm(v$x)
    v$title <- "T-distribution"
}

geddistr <- function(v){
    v$x <- seq(-10, 10, by = .1)
    v$y <- rnorm(v$x)
    v$title <- "GED distribution"
}

server = function(input, output,session) { 

    observe({
        onclick("01",normal(v))
        onclick("02",tdistr(v))
        onclick("03",geddistr(v))
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        req(v$x)
        plot(v$x,v$y,main = v$title)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pork Chop. Is there a way to make this happen within a `shiny::showModal` ?