# Error with renderPlot but not renderPrint when using shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

While trying to help [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60752449/generate-different-clickable-events-on-divs-in-shiny-app), I got stuck with a problem with `shinyjs`. I would like to display a plot when I click on the rectangle in the code below.

In the example below, clicking on the big green rectangle prints the text, as it should be:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id = "01", 
      style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", 
      HTML("01")),
  textOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  onclick(id = "01", {
    output$plot <- renderPrint({
      print("foo")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, if I try to replace the print with a plot, I am facing the error:

> Warning: Error in origRenderFunc: argument "name" missing, with no default

Here's the code that creates the error:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id = "01", 
      style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", 
      HTML("01")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  onclick(id = "01", {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(mtcars)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I suppose the problem comes from the function `onclick` since I can't reproduce this error if I put `renderPlot` outside of `onclick`. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put plot() outside of onclick() and it works

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id = "01", 
      style = "cursor:pointer; height: 300px; width: 300px; text-align: center; background-color: green", 
      HTML("01")),
  fluidRow(plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  p <- output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(mtcars))

  onclick("01", p)
```

Comment: not working for two reasons: 1) the plot is displayed before I click on the rectangle and 2) clicking on the rectangle crashes the app with the same error